# Concerning extendable fixed elements in webpage

Tags: html, css, layout, css-position

I was trying to customize a theme for a CMS(ocPortal/vanilla) where I wanted the sidebar to be fixed along with the header. Making it fixed it not a tough job, but the problem is that the end user can add widgets to the sidebar which can run out of screen height. And then the fixed attribute would become useless.

Is there a solution to this problem as I have not been able to come around with anything.

Comment: Set the overflow-y to scroll on the sidebar?

Comment: @RickCalder Ah yes. I had thought about that. But it looked very, if you would allow me to say, uncool. But still thanks for the answer.

Comment: Yeah isn't the most elegant solution I agree =)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple solutions to this problem, seeing you have not given an example, I will assume these widgets can be added and removed dynamically (meaning at anytime after page load). Assuming this, I have two possible solutions that you can try.

**Solution 1 :**

Try making each widget inside a tabbed/spoiler type container, so they become small when the end user does not need them at that point in time

**Solution 2 :**

As *Rick Calder* mentioned, you can also use the CSS rule `overflow-y: scroll;` so when the contents of your sidebar becomes larger than the height, a scroll-bar appears allowing the user to scroll through your widgets.

You may also combine these solutions together, to enable a LOT of widgets, dependent on what your personal preference is.

I hope this helps!

**NOTE :**

A simple search for *html javascript spoilers* will give you MANY examples of spoilers.